# In a PowerShell script, how can I check if I'm running with administrator privileges?

Tags: powershell

In a PowerShell script, how can I check if I'm running with administrator privileges?

Comment: [Check for Admin Credentials in a PowerShell Script](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/11/check-for-admin-credentials-in-a-powershell-script.aspx)

Comment: Archived version of the link in the previous comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150711220515/http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/11/check-for-admin-credentials-in-a-powershell-script.aspx

Comment: Where Microsoft has currently moved it to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/check-for-admin-credentials-in-a-powershell-script/

Comment: Last link no longer works, but archive of it: https://web.archive.org/web/https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/check-for-admin-credentials-in-a-powershell-script/

Answer (score 127, accepted):

```
$currentPrincipal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
$currentPrincipal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
```

(from [Command line safety tricks](https://serverfault.com/questions/11320/command-line-safety-tricks/29261#29261))

Comment: $currentPrincipal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal( [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent() )
    &{
     if ($currentPrincipal.IsInRole( [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator ))
     {
            (get-host).UI.RawUI.Backgroundcolor="DarkRed"
            clear-host
            write-host "Warning: PowerShell is running as an Administrator.`n"
     }

Comment: This is a great solution where you are using an ancient version of powershell (in my case 3) that doesn't support "#Requires -RunAsAdministrator"

Comment: Single line without variable assignment: `(New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)`

Comment: @gm3do Like the person asking (probably), yes I want to actually use the value like in your comment... but PowerShell says "The ampersand (&) character is not allowed." Please fix the code and place it in a code block so it isn't mangled by the site: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189

Answer (score 137):

To cause your script to not run if not run as administrator:

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires

Outputs:

> The script 'MyScript.ps1' cannot be run because it contains a "#requires"       statement for
> running as Administrator. The current Windows PowerShell session is not running as Administrator. Start Windows
> PowerShell by  using the Run as Administrator option, and then try running the script again.

Introduced in PowerShell 4.0.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but still very useful.  Thanks Eddie!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: correkt link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires

Comment: Neat solution, but the downside of it is if you run the script from the file explorer > right click > Run in Powershell (instead of running it from a terminal). In this case, the window blinks for half a second and the message cannot be read by the user.

Comment: It's a neat idea but doesn't address the need where you want the script behavior to be different depending on whether it's running with admin privileges or not.

Answer (score 49):

```
function Test-Administrator  
{  
    $user = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
    (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $user).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)  
}
```

Execute the above function. IF the a result is True, the user has admin privileges.

Comment: This only determines if the user running the script is an administrator on the machine -- and not if the script is currently being **executed with administrative privileges**. In other words, this will still return true even if the user did not use "run as administrator" to launch the command shell.

Comment: @HolisticDeveloper, that is incorrect. If you aren't elevated, it will return false

Comment: @charleswj81 as of now I observe the behavior that Holistic Developer describes.

Comment: I don't think you need the semi colon... but that said I don't think it throws an error either

Comment: This works for me on Win10 as of 2018. Returns False if current user account is not elevated, returns True if powershell is running elevated.

Comment: Exactly what i was searching for.

Comment: Hello, 2022 chiming in with testing this in admin and non-admin shells. Returns true in the former, false in the latter for me.

Answer (score 3):

as a combination of the above answers, you can use something like the following at the begin of your script:

```perl
# todo: put this in a dedicated file for reuse and dot-source the file
function Test-Administrator  
{  
    [OutputType([bool])]
    param()
    process {
        [Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal]$user = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
        return $user.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator);
    }
}

if(-not (Test-Administrator))
{
    # TODO: define proper exit codes for the given errors 
    Write-Error "This script must be executed as Administrator.";
    exit 1;
}

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";

# do something
```

Another method is to start your Script with this line, which will prevent it's execution when not started with admin rights.

```perl
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  If the script is not run with elevated rights, then it won't even load, and you won't see your custom error message.

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

This will check if you are an Administrator, if not then it will reopen in PowerShell ISE as an Administrator.

Hope this helps!

```
    $ver = $host | select version
    if ($ver.Version.Major -gt 1)  {$Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"}

    # Verify that user running script is an administrator
    $IsAdmin=[Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
    If ((New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $IsAdmin).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator) -eq $FALSE)
    {
      "`nERROR: You are NOT a local administrator.  Run this script after logging on with a local administrator account."
        # We are not running "as Administrator" - so relaunch as administrator

        # Create a new process object that starts PowerShell
        $newProcess = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell_ise";

        # Specify the current script path and name as a parameter
        $newProcess.Arguments = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition;

        # Indicate that the process should be elevated
        $newProcess.Verb = "runas";

        # Start the new process
        [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);

        # Exit from the current, unelevated, process
        exit
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on it, if the script isn't run as an administrator, it reloads it and access for administrator access

```
if (-not (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
# Prompt the user to elevate the script
$arguments = "& '" + $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "'"
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
exit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Test-RunAsAdministrator{
   $script = new-item -path $env:TEMP -name 'TestElevated.ps1' -value @'
      #Requires -RunAsAdministrator
      $true
'@
   
   try{
      & $script.FullName
   }catch [System.Management.Automation.ScriptRequiresException]{
      $false
   }finally{
      remove-item $script.FullName
   }
}
```

This is a function wrapper for the `#Requires` statement, it should return:

- `$true`, when run in an elevated context
- `$false`, when run in a non-elevated context

Although in my current test scenarios it provides the same results as using the `GetCurrent()`

|  | Admin User | Non-Admin User |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Elevated Proc** | `$true` | N/A |
| **Non Elevated Proc** | `$false` | `$false` |

```perl
$IsAdministrator = ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal]::new(
   ($id = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
)).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
$id.dispose(); remove-variable id
```