# Windows 10 non-server edition Remote Shell

Tags: windows, shell, remote

There a are two computers connected to the local network managed under organization domain.

There are simple task list must be implemented on any machine. I want to abstract away that machine list to a script that can be executed simultaneously on any machine.

Now, I am trying to get interactive admin remote shell. Like SSH on linux machines.

Any machine can ping second one.

Any machine has latest PowerShell deployed.

Any machine configured via

```
winrm quickconfig
Enable-PSRemoting
```

Let's expose one machine and call it 'admin pc'.

Also let's expose one random non-admin pc.

Next command successfully executed at admin pc.

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName some_name -Credential domain\name
```

and I got interactive connection.

On [that page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession?view=powershell-7.1) noted necessary for me parameter to get admin shell, `-RunAsAdministrator`, but it doesn't work.

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName some_name -Credential domain\name -RunAsAdministrator


Enter-PSSession : Не удается разрешить набор параметров с использованием указанных именованных параметров.
строка:1 знак:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName some_name -Credential domain\nam ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Enter-PSSession], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.EnterPSSessionCommand
```

What can cause the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an elevated admin session on the remote computer you don't need to use `-RunAsAdministrator`, just connect with a user that is an administrator on the remote machine. The remote session is already elevated.

The `-RunAsAdministrator` switch can only be used together with the `-ContainerId` parameter when connecting to a container not when connecting to a remote session.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Code https://serverfault.com/a/95464/621126 returns false. I have logged in under domain user that have limited, but on pc-level root access. And, why flag `-RunAsAdministrator` is syntactically incorrect?

Comment: I updated my answer about -RunAsAdministrator. I don't know why your session is not elevated. A domain user who is in the local administrator group should work. What does `whoami /groups` return when executed in the remote session?

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov: PowerShell has the concept of parameter sets, RunAsAdministrator is incompatible with other parameters that are not part of the same set.

Comment: Problem was simple - I have not be presented at local machine admin group.